# Картинка не выравнивается по центру

Tags: изображения, выравнивание, вёрстка, css

Почему не выравнивается?

[КОД](http://jsfiddle.net/68xoz40o/1/)

Comment: Потому что по умолчанию у нее `display: inline`, и надо либо проставлять `display: block`, либо центрировать за счет `text-align: center`.

P.S. Вам вообще удобно с таким форматированием работать?

Comment: text-align:center; не работает...а вот display - да.Спасибо!не знаю что там по поводу форматирования) я только учусь

Answer (score 2):

Потому что никаких оснований нет ей выравниваться.
Задан `margin: auto` как для блочных элементов, но `img` строковой.

Вы уж либо `display: block` картинке дайте, либо `text-align: center` контейнеру.